# Download feature not working within update panel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a Web User Control containing a `FormView`. The formview shows details of job seeker. I have provided a button for "Download Resume" link, so that admin/HR can download the resume. I have placed this control in an aspx page that contains the UpdatePanel. Everything works fine except Download Link.

I have given a Command on donwload link button and a function is associated with the command to start download.

Below is the code i have implemented -

```
//Command on 'Download' link button within FormView
protected void lnkDownload_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("Download"))
    {
        StartDownload(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    }
}

//My routine to download document
//sFileInfo contains filepath$==$mimetype
protected void StartDownload(string sFileInfo)
{
    string[] d = sFileInfo.ToString().Split((new string[] { "$==$" }), StringSplitOptions.None);
    string filename = d[0];
    string docType = d[1];

    System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(d[0]);

    if (file.Exists)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + d[0]);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = d[1];
        Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
        Response.End();
    }
    else
    {
        Server.Transfer("~/Mesgbox.aspx?cat=2");
    }
}
```

The code works perfectly if update panel is removed but generates script errors if update panel is used.

Any suggestions....?

Thanks for sharing your time.

Comment: have you added an asp:ScriptManager to the page?

Comment: </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="YourControlID" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

Comment: Have you found the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

To initiate a full page postback, you add a postback trigger to your update panel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="YourControlID" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        .....
```

Comment: Above question is about User Control, where can i add Triggers to it?

Comment: this does not answer if you are trying to download a file with Response

Comment: @MichaelRudnerEvanchik - It answers "Download feature not working within update panel in asp.net" Key was PostBackTrigger and NOT AsyncPost..... Thank you Mitul

Answer (score 29):

You cannot return an attachment in an UpdatePanel partial postback, since the results are used by the ScriptManager to update a DIV (not the whole response). The simplest fix for what you're trying to do would be to make your download button as a postback control. That would cause that button to initiate a full postback. Here's the code below to include in your Page_Load

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterPostBackControl(this.lnkDownload);
```

Comment: I forget this every time - bookmarking for future reference... better than trying to make all my UpdatePanels regular Panels!

Comment: If the download button is in a user control, and the UpdatePanel is in its parent page, this solution is surely the appropriate one as the registration can be done in the user control's page_load event.

Answer (score 7):

You can still trigger download doc from inside an Update Panel.

I have an update panel and inside I have 3 nested repeaters. In the most inner repeater I build a series of download links using LinkButtons, each one containing a command to fetch the document via webservice and dispatching it.

Each repeater has an OnItemDataBound method. In the last repeater I have the following

```
        protected void LinkDocRepeaterOnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
            if(!(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)) {
            return;
                }
            LinkButton linkButton = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControlRecursive("LinkId");
            var scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
            if (scriptManager != null) {
               scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(linkButton);
            }
        }
```

Each Linkbutton now downloads a document.

Comment: This saved a day. Thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

My situation:

I had a long running excel file loaded from sql data and I wanted update progress panel to display the spinner gif while the file was created and then download the file from within the update panel. It was trickier than I thought.

This link came up high on searches and after trying to avoid it, it turned out that an iframe was useful to me.

[iframe async download](http://encosia.com/ajax-file-downloads-and-iframes/)

Here is what ended up working.. (this exact code has not been tested)

MyPage.aspx...(inside update panel, no triggers)

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnExcelExport" Text="Export to Excel" OnClick="btnExcelExport_Click" />

<iframe runat="server" id="ifmExcel" width="0" height="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
                    frameborder="0" />
```

MyPage.aspx.cs

```
        protected void btnExcelExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //long running process here, taking advantage of the update progress panel
            var bytes = GetExcelFile();
            //generate a key to pass to the download page to access the file bytes
            var cacheKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");//N means no hyphens
            //placing the result in cache for a few seconds so the download page can grab it             
            Context.Cache.Insert(key: cacheKey, value: bytes, dependencies: null, absoluteExpiration: DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30), slidingExpiration: System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
            ifmExcel.Attributes.Add("src", String.Format("MyDownloadPage.aspx?cacheKey={0}", cacheKey));
        }
```

MyDownloadPage.aspx.cs...

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var bytes = Context.Cache.Get(Request.QueryString.Get("cacheKey")) as byte[];
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader(
                "content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}.xlsx", "Invoice"));
            Response.ContentType = "application/xlsx";
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

It seems to work as expected like any other async post back would.

Answer (score 1):

ASPX markup:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="gv_Files" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="7" OnPageIndexChanging="gv_Files_PageIndexChanging" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No files uploaded" GridLines="None">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Filename" HeaderText="File Name"  ItemStyle-CssClass="Files_css"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateCreated" HeaderText="Upload Date" ItemStyle-CssClass="Files_css"  />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text="Download" CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FileName_Guid")+  ";" + Eval("Filename")  %>' runat="server" OnClick="DownloadFile"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" Text="Del" CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FileName_Guid")+ ";" + Eval("File_ID")+ ";" + Eval("Filename") + ";" + Eval("Platform_Config_ID") %>' runat="server" OnClick="DeleteFile" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <%--<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gv_Files" />--%>                   
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind:

```
    protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            string extension = "." + FileName.Split('.')[1].ToString();
            string FileName_Guid = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid()) + extension;
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(@"C:\Uploads\" + FileName_Guid);
            string Platform_Config_ID = PlatformConfigID.Value;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = DAL.Upload_File(FileName_Guid, FileName, Platform_Config_ID);

            gv_Files.DataSource = dt;
            gv_Files.DataBind();
            ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
            scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(gv_Files);
        }
    }

    protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {                
            LinkButton lnkDownload = (LinkButton)sender;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)lnkDownload.NamingContainer;
            LinkButton download = row.FindControl("lnkDownload") as LinkButton;
            ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(download);
            string FileName = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument.Split(';')[0].ToString();
            string OriginalFileName = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument.Split(';')[1].ToString();
            string FilePath = @"C:\Uploads\" + FileName.ToString();
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(FilePath);
            if (file.Exists)
            {                    
                Response.ContentType = ContentType;
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + OriginalFileName);
                Response.Headers.Set("Cache-Control", "private, max-age=0");
                Response.WriteFile(FilePath);                    
                Response.End();                                     
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }


    protected void DeleteFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FileName_Guid = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument.Split(';')[0].ToString();
        string File_ID = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument.Split(';')[1].ToString();
        string Filename = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument.Split(';')[2].ToString();
        string Platform_Config_ID = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument.Split(';')[3].ToString();
        string FilePath = @"C:\Uploads\" + FileName_Guid;
        File.Delete(FilePath);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = DAL.Delete_File(File_ID, Filename, Platform_Config_ID);

        gv_Files.DataSource = dt;
        gv_Files.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Step1:                                                                                 
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">

Comment: Make Sure the Update Panel mode is set like this:  UpdateMode="Conditional" and then follow the steps I have shown above in the code behind. You have to register the control as a postbackcontrol in the codebehind. It works like a charm !!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Response object in update panel.

Comment: That is what my question is. Response.WriteFile() is generating the error. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps:

1. ```
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server" l**UpdateMode="Conditional"**>
   <asp:GridView ID="gv_Files" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="7" OnPageIndexChanging="gv_Files_PageIndexChanging" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No files uploaded" GridLines="None">
   ```
2. (Code Behind) `UploadFile()`

   ```
   ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
   scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(gv_Files);
   ```
3. `DownloadFile()`

   ```
   DownloadFile() --> LinkButton download = row.FindControl("lnkDownload") as LinkButton;
   ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(download);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

aspx page

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">

 <ContentTemplate>

     <asp:LinkButton ID="CmdExportPDF" runat="server" onclick="YourCode"      Text="PDF" >PDF </asp:LinkButton>

 </ContentTemplate>

 <Triggers>

          <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="CmdExportPDF" />

 </Triggers>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```