# File is broken when downloading from LinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my ASP code, I have a LinkButton for my file upload:

```
<asp:Linkbutton ID="lnkContract" Text="" runat="server" Visible="false" onclick="lnkContract_Click"></asp:Linkbutton>
```

I manage to write a code in C# that triggers a file download in `lnkContract_Click` here:

```
protected void lnkContract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] strFileType = lnkContract.Text.Split('.');
    string strPath = Server.MapPath("~") + FilePath.CUST_DEALS + lnkContract.Text;
    Open(lnkContract.Text, strFileType[1], strPath);
}


private void Open(string strFile, string strType, string strPath)
{
    FileInfo fiPath = new FileInfo(@strPath);

    //opens download dialog box
    try
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/" + strType.ToLower();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + strFile + "\"");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fiPath.Length.ToString());
        Response.TransmitFile(fiPath.FullName);
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        Response.Clear();
    }//try
    catch
    {
        ucMessage.ShowMessage(UserControl_Message.MessageType.WARN, CustomerDefine.NOFILE);
    }//catch if file is not found
}
```

when I click the `LinkButton` the file automatically downloads but when I open the file, it is broken (or if the file is `.jpeg` the file shows an "**x**"). Where did I go wrong?

**Update**
LinkButton is under UpdatePanel.

Comment: Is the file you download of any size or just 0kb?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The file size is as is. Not 0.

Comment: Try using `Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"` and see what the result is.

Comment: Still don't work sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the second `Response.Clear();` replace it with `Response.End();` to flush the buffer and send all the data to the client.

You will have a problem with your code though, which is, that `Response.End()` actually causes a Thread abort exception, therefore, you should be more specific in the exception you catch.

**UPDATE:**

In your comments you mentioned that this is running within an `UpdatePanel`. In that scenario, this will not work. You will have to force that link button to execute a regular postback instead of an ajax one.

Here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5461736/1373170

Comment: Sir, I remember that `Response.End();` pawn an error that is why I replace it with `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();`

Comment: Correct, but it's not an error, that's how it's supposed to work. But you shouldn't use a catch-all type of try-catch in there. You should catch and handle exceptions that you are actually expecting your code to throw. Other type of general error handling should be done separately, not through try-catch, like handling Application_OnError or that type of thing.

Comment: Even though a remove the catch, there will be no file(downloaded). Simply the linkbutton will postback or the page will refresh.

Comment: I forgot to mention. Is there an effect if I put it in an `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: Oh, definitely, this won't work in an update panel, since that call is being handled by javascript. You should exclude that button from being a trigger within the updatePanel and execute it like a standard postback. Here's how: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5461736/1373170

Comment: I already added an `AsynchPostBackTrigger` for my LinkButton sir. But same error appears.

Comment: So you are saying that I should use a `PostBackTrigger` instead of the `AsynchPostBack`?

Answer (score 2):

Try using this function that I'm shamelessly lifting from http://forums.asp.net/post/3561663.aspx to get the content type:

(Use it with your fiPath.Extension)

```
public static string GetFileContentType(string fileextension)
{
    //set the default content-type
    const string DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/unknown";

    RegistryKey regkey, fileextkey;
    string filecontenttype;

    //the file extension to lookup
    //fileextension = ".zip";

    try
    {
        //look in HKCR
        regkey = Registry.ClassesRoot;

        //look for extension
        fileextkey = regkey.OpenSubKey(fileextension);

        //retrieve Content Type value
        filecontenttype = fileextkey.GetValue("Content Type", DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE).ToString();

        //cleanup
        fileextkey = null;
        regkey = null;
    }
    catch
    {
        filecontenttype = DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE;
    }

    //print the content type
    return filecontenttype;
}
```

Comment: This would just be a static method accessible from your Open method. Then you just need to reference it by replacing `Response.ContentType = "application/" + strType.ToLower();` with `Response.ContentType =  GetFileContentType(fiPath.Extension);`

Comment: Wow. It works like magic for my file type problem. Thank you for that. But the problem here in my post still exists.

Comment: Can you send a simple text file across it and see if it's corrupted at all when you open it on the other side?