# download file (Image Button ) option is not working in UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net

In gridview There is an image button to download file. I have used the gridview with updatepanel.If I removed Updatepanel the download option will work fine.But i have to use Updatepanel in this.How can Isolve this?

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" >
                        <ContentTemplate>
               <asp:GridView ID="GridImport" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="99%" Height="50%"
                                    AllowPaging="true" GridLines="None" Style="padding: 15px; text-align: left; overflow: scroll;
                                    font-family: Arial; font-size: 11pt;" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" PageSize="5"
                                    CssClass="Grid_LE" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Grid_Head" EmptyDataText = "No files Imported" OnPageIndexChanging="GridImport_PageIndexChanging">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="File Name" />
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>'  Style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" ImageUrl="~/Images/download.png" OnClick = "DownloadFile"  />   <%--CommandName="Upload"  OnClick="DownloadFile"--%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>'  Style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" ImageUrl="~/Images/cancel.png" OnClick="DeleteFile" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
           </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**.cs**

```
   protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filePath = (sender as ImageButton).CommandArgument;
            Response.ContentType = ContentType;
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
            Response.WriteFile(filePath);
            Response.End();
        }
        protected void DeleteFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filePath = (sender as ImageButton).CommandArgument;
            File.Delete(filePath);
            ExprotFileList();
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Val", "ShowExpPopup();", true);
        }
```

Comment: put page load if (!IsPostBack){}?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461525/download-feature-not-working-within-update-panel-in-asp-net

Comment: <Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="YourControlID" />
  </Triggers>

Comment: I tried with iths code.<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkDownload" />
  </Triggers> Is it Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code file:

```
protected void ClickFromUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string filePath = (sender as ImageButton).CommandArgument;
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "DownloadScript", "$(function() {DownloadFile(" + filePath + ");});", true);
}

protected void DownloadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Your download code
     var filePath = Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
     Response.ContentType = ContentType;
     Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
     Response.WriteFile(filePath);
     Response.End();
}
```

In your markup file inside the updatepanel:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>'  Style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" ImageUrl="~/Images/download.png" OnClick = "ClickFromUpdate_Click"  />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In your markup file add this button outside your updatepanel:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonDownload"  OnClick="DownloadFile_Click" runat="server" />
```

Javascript code:

```
function DownloadFile(filepath) {
            __doPostBack("<%= ButtonDownload.UniqueID %>", filepath);
        }
```

Comment: please say what is 'ClickFromUpdate_Click'?

Comment: Sorry jithesh. The method "ClickFromUpdate_Click" is called from the gridview. My code example is updated with that code.

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply.But '  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "DownloadScript", "$(function() {DownloadFile(" + filePath + ");});", true);           is not calling the 'DownloadFile' function in my code.?

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(ImageButton), "scr", "DownloadFile('" + filePath + "');", true);     .Its working fine .....Thanks for your great help.

Answer (score 0):

use `trigger` in your code

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" >
                        <ContentTemplate>
               <asp:GridView ID="GridImport" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="99%" Height="50%"
                                    AllowPaging="true" GridLines="None" Style="padding: 15px; text-align: left; overflow: scroll;
                                    font-family: Arial; font-size: 11pt;" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" PageSize="5"
                                    CssClass="Grid_LE" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Grid_Head" EmptyDataText = "No files Imported" OnPageIndexChanging="GridImport_PageIndexChanging">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="File Name" />
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>'  Style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" ImageUrl="~/Images/download.png" OnClick = "DownloadFile"  />   <%--CommandName="Upload"  OnClick="DownloadFile"--%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>'  Style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" ImageUrl="~/Images/cancel.png" OnClick="DeleteFile" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
           </ContentTemplate>
       <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkDownload" /> **Or**
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkDownload" EventName="OnClick" />
        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: A control with ID 'lnkDownload' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel2'.   This error is getting

Comment: A control with ID 'lnkDownload' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel2'.  The same error is getting

Comment: This will not work - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4937603/1191903 for correct way to register the trigger

Comment: <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>